# Error for inline and Rcpp packages

Tags: r, rcpp

I am using R 2.15.1 on Windows 7, and I got an error message when I run the following R-code. Does anyone help me?

```
> library(inline)
> 
> if( require( Rcpp ) ){
+   fx <- cxxfunction( signature(x = "integer", y = "numeric" ) , '
+   return wrap( as<int>(x) * as<double>(y) ) ;
+   ', plugin = "Rcpp" )
+ }
Loading required package: Rcpp
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/R/R-215~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/R/R-215~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
  Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
  make: *** [file11a82c84184d.dll] Error 2

ERROR(s) during compilation: source code errors or compiler configuration errors!

Program source:
  1: 
  2: // includes from the plugin
  3: 
  4: #include <Rcpp.h>
  5: 
  6: 
  7: #ifndef BEGIN_RCPP
  8: #define BEGIN_RCPP
  9: #endif
 10: 
 11: #ifndef END_RCPP
 12: #define END_RCPP
 13: #endif
 14: 
 15: using namespace Rcpp;
 16: 
 17: 
 18: // user includes
 19: 
 20: 
 21: // declarations
 22: extern "C" {
 23: SEXP file11a82c84184d( SEXP x, SEXP y) ;
 24: }
 25: 
 26: // definition
 27: 
 28: SEXP file11a82c84184d( SEXP x, SEXP y ){
 29: BEGIN_RCPP
 30: 
 31:   return wrap( as<int>(x) * as<double>(y) ) ;
 32:   
 33: END_RCPP
 34: }
 35: 
 36: 
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/R/R-215~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/R/R-215~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
make: *** [file11a82c84184d.dll] Error 2
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'C:/R/R-2.15.1/bin/i386/R CMD SHLIB file11a82c84184d.cpp 2> file11a82c84184d.cpp.err.txt' had status 1 
>
```

Comment: In addition to Dirk's answer below, you could follow this post where the author had the problem. http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-rcpp-on-windows-7-for-r-and-c-integration/

Comment: That is a convoluted post. How to install a compiler for R on Windows is explained in dozens of tutorials.  In short, do NOT mix with Cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

Works here under Linux (though I made small changes / simplifications):

```
R> library(inline)
R> fx <- cxxfunction(signature(x = "integer", y = "numeric" ),
+                   body = 'return wrap( as<int>(x) * as<double>(y) );',
+                   plugin = "Rcpp" )
R> print(fx(2, 2.5))
R> [1] 5
R>
```

If you set the environment variable `CYGWIN` to `nodosfilewarning` you will get a little bit less of line noise on Windows.

Comment: Thank you, but I have no idea about the environmental variables. I just installed R, R tools, and CYGWIN on windows 7